# как сделать, чтобы при достижении лимита sum, блокировать нажатие на кнопку JS

Tags: javascript

я бы хотел узнать, какими способами возможно реализовать блокировку кнопки, если достигнут лимит переменной, допустим, максимум 20 нажатий, потом кнопку блокировать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let button_click_counter = 0;

myForm.onsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    button_click_counter++;
    if (button_click_counter >= 20) button.disabled = true;

    button.innerText = `SUBMIT ${button_click_counter}`;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
    <button type="submit" id="button">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```js
let a = document.getElementById("a");
let b = document.getElementById("b");

limit_clicks(a, 10);
limit_clicks(b, 5);

/***/
function limit_clicks(elem, limit) {
  
  elem.addEventListener("click", function _tmp() {
    // Добавляется еще один временный обработчик клика;

    if (--limit <= 0) { // уменьшает limit на 1.
      // Дошло до нуля?
      this.disabled = true; // Отключить кнопку,
      this.removeEventListener("click", _tmp); // Удалить обработчик клика.
    }
    
    this.textContent = "Осталось: " + limit;
  });
  
}
```

```html
<button id="a">Click</button>
<button id="b">Click</button>
```